# ERR_TRADE_NOT_ALLOWED only for debugging mode

Tags: mql4

I try to debug my code but I get error `4109 (ERR_TRADE_NOT_ALLOWED)` when I send order:

```
orderId = OrderSend(
    Symbol(), orderType,
    lotVolume, price, 3,
    Bid - StopLoss * Point,
    Bid + TakeProfit * Point
);
```

This common error for not allowed trading, but I set checkbox `Allow live trading`.

It Error appears only in debug mode, not looking at my settings.
Maybe for debug mode I should set something additional permissions?

Comment: [This](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/102092) might help you...